# Lotteries = probability distribution?

Tags: consumer-theory, uncertainty

Are "lotteries" in the model for choice under uncertainty not just probability distributions?

Comment: Usually, yes. Details may vary (finite support or not, countable vs finite additivity...)

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. See for example this passage from [Choice under Uncertainty by Jonathan Levin](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejdlevin/Econ%20202/Uncertainty.pdf):

> #### 2.1  Prizes and Lotteries
>
> The starting point for the model is a set $X$ of possible *prizes* or *consequences*. In many economic problems (and for much of this class), $X$ will be a set of monetary payoffs. But it need not be. If we are considering who will win Big Game this year, the set of consequences might be:
> $$X=\lbrace\text{Stanford wins}, \text{Cal wins}, \text{Tie}\rbrace.$$
> We represent an uncertain prospect as a *lottery* or *probability distribution* over the prize space. For instance, the prospect that Stanford and Cal are equally likely to win Big Game can be written as $p=(1/2,1/2,0)$. Perhaps these probabilities depend on who Stanford starts at quarterback. In that case, there might be two prospects: $p$ or $p'=(5/9,3/9,1/9)$, depending on who starts.

<sub>(not sure what I was thinking yesterday evening. It seems like I completely misunderstood the question)</sub>

Comment: I think they mean lotteries in the MWG sense of uncertain cash flow, not real life lotteries, which are a subset of this.

Comment: @Giskard you are right. if you can come with a better answer please do

Comment: @Xenusi I think Michael Greinecker's comment is the appropriate answer.